# Finding the correct adapter for a device

Tags: usb, power-supply

I need some help ensuring that I purchase the correct adapters for two devices I own as I have no idea.

I have two devices I bought in the UK that have the standard UK G style plug. Both use the USB adapters. An IP camera and an Amazon Firestick. I'm now living outside the UK - same v and Hz as UK, just differnet plug style, C/F - and want to continue using the devices and not have to use a travel converter, especially for the camera as this will stay on around 12 hours a day. So, I need to buy two USB adapters for them in the C/F style plug.

Below is what's written on each device plus what's listed on the original USB adapter plug that came with them.

Camera
Device: DC 5V 2A

USB adapter: AC/DC Adapter Input: 100-240v ~ 0.2A Max 50/60Hz Output: 5.0V ⎓ 1200 mA

Firestick
Device: Can't find device info

USB adapter: AC Adapter Input: 100-240v ~ 0.15A 50/60Hz Output: 5.0V ⎓ 1.0A

I can't seem to find any USB adapters that match the exact above details input and output. What therefore should I be looking for in an adapter that's safe to use?

Should I just be looking for adapters that have greater input and output ratings than the current UK plugs I have, seeing as I can't find the exact same ones? I've seen the phone charger style USB adapters that have something like 5.0v 2.1A output. Assuming input listed on the adapter is the same/greater than the device, is this safe to use as the output is greater?

Thank you!

Comment: How good are you with a screwdriver & wire strippers? Just lop the plugs off & replace with home versions. Put F plugs on if the PSUs are earthed, otherwise C will do. [General rule for replacement PSUs, btw. Voltage & polarity must match, amperage can be equal or greater - amps are 'pulled' by the device, not 'pushed' by the PSU.]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Sorry, should have worded my question a little better. Have now edited it. Both devices use a USB cable and adapter, so no plug to loop off in this case.

So based on your second part, I've found a USB adapter for the Firestick that has nearly the same as the original adapter, only difference being the Output is listed as 5.0v ⎓ 2.1A instead of the ⎓ 1.0A on the original adapter. This would be safe to use then?

Comment: Should be, so long as the polarities are right. A lot of PSUs these days are variations on a theme, if they have a USB socket, they're pretty much all interchangeable.